# Invoke feign client using URL

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign, feign

I have a URL : http://localhost:8080/company  and want to use feign client to invoke the service. Lets say I want to do it dynamically during runtime and I don't know which interface I need to Autowire and which method I need to invoke.

Is it possible to autowire a feign client and invoke a given method by just using the url?

Thank you all for your time.

Edit:
The below code works perfectly fine for the CompanySearch class invoking CompanyApi service and getting the data.

**Feign Client**

```
@FeignClient(name = "companyClient" ,url = "http://localhost:9000")
public interface CompanyApi {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,path = "/company")
    Company companyInfo();

   }

@FeignClient(name = "employeeClient" ,url = "http://localhost:9001")
    public interface CompanyApi {

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET,path = "/employee")
        Employee employeeInfo();

       }
```

Service Method:

```
  @Component
    public class CompanySearch {

    @Autowired
    CompanyApi companyApi;

   @Autowired
    EmployeeApi employeeApi;

      public Snapshot snapshot(){
            Company company = companyApi.companyInfo();
            Employee employee = employeeApi.employeeInfo();
            return new Snapshot(company,employee);
    }
```

I wanted to check if there is a way to something like this with feign. I can accomplish this Apache's HttpClient and want to explore Feign's equivalent.

```
  public Snapshot snapshot(){
         this.client = Feign.builder().target("http://localhost:9000/company").build();

         if(client instanceof CompanyApi.class) {
             Company company = ((companyApi)client).companyInfo();
          }     
        }
```

Comment: I'm afraid i don't understand, can you show your feign client?